# A question on irreducible unitary representations of the unitary group $ U(n)$

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, unitary-matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $U(n)$ be the group of $n\times n$ unitary matrices. I have two question regarding the irreducible unitary representations of $U(n)$.

1. Is there any irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $U(n)$ such that $1<\dim \pi < n$, where $\dim \pi$ is the dimension of the corresponding representation space.
2. Let $\pi_1:U(n)\to GL_n(C)$ and $\pi_2:U(n)\to GL_n(C)$ be defined by
   $$\pi_1(u)=u,~~~\pi_2(u)=\overline u,~u\in U(n).$$
   Here $\overline{u}$ is the conjugate matrix of $u$.
   Clearly, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are two irreducible unitary representation  of $U(n)$ where the  dimension of the corresponding representation space is $n$. Are these all irreducible unitary representation  of $U(n)$ (upto unitary equivalence) where the dimension of the corresponding representation space is $n$?

I know that there is a Weyl dimension formula for  irreducible unitary representation  of $U(n)$.
But I was not able to solve the above questions using that formula. Also I am very new in this area. Any help or reference will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (1), the dimension of the image (assuming nontrivial) is at least $n^2-1$ (because $SU(n)$), but the image is also a compact subgroup so must be contained in the maximal compact subgroup, which is $U(m)$ of dimension $m^2$.